# Why the AVAudioPlayer var equals nil? - Swift

Tags: swift, null, avaudioplayer, nsbundle

This is my function:

```
func playMusic(filename :String!) {
    var playIt : AVAudioPlayer!
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
    if url == nil {
        println("could not find \(filename)")
        return
    }
    var error : NSError?
    playIt = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
    if playIt==nil {
        println("could not create audio player")
        return
    }
    playIt.numberOfLoops = -1
    playIt.prepareToPlay()
    playIt.play()
}
```

I debugged my app and i saw that the console tells me: could't create audio player

it looks like my `playIt` var is nil

how do i fix it?

Comment: Have you checked the value of your `error` variable?

Comment: `error` holds the answer to your question.  It's probably also worth checking the value of `url` just to be sure it is what you think it is... also, you shouldn't accept a `String!` argument... either take `String` or `String?`...

Comment: Most people tend to avoid force-unwrapping (!), always opt to go for conditionals(?). As Joey deVilla said. This is to prevent any crashes to your app should they return nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There's another problem with your code: once you find out why `playIt` is `nil` and fix that, you'll discover that `playMusic` runs without errors, but no sound plays.** That's because you've declared `playIt` as a local variable inside `playMusic`. Just as it starts playing, you reach the end of `playMusic`, when all its local variables go out of scope and cease to exist. Microseconds after `playIt` starts to play, it gets wiped out of existence.

To fix this, declare `playIt` outside `playMusic`, as an instance variable. Here's the code for a view controller that uses your `playMusic` method with my one suggested change:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {

  // Declare playIt here instead
  var playIt : AVAudioPlayer!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    playMusic("sad trombone.mp3")
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

  }

  func playMusic(filename :String!) {
    // var playIt : AVAudioPlayer! *** this is where you originally declared playIt
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: nil)
    if url == nil {
      println("could not find \(filename)")
      return
    }
    var error : NSError?
    playIt = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
    if playIt==nil {
      println("could not create audio player")
      return
    }
    playIt.numberOfLoops = -1
    playIt.prepareToPlay()
    playIt.play()
  }

}
```

Try it both ways -- with `playIt` declared as an instance variable, and `playIt` as a local variable inside `playMusic`. You'll want to go with the former.

I'm also seconding nhgrif's suggestion: playMusic should take a `String` or `String?` parameter; not `String!`